# cant print the same value outside loop

Tags: loops, binary

```
    int randomDecimal = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 255);
    int division = (int) Math.ceil(randomDecimal / 2);
    String binaryNumber = "";
    int remainder;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        division = (int) Math.ceil(division / 2);
        remainder = division % 2;
        binaryNumber = remainder + "";
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(binaryNumber);
```

the problem is that it should print a random 8 digit binary number like (10110010) but instead it just prints 0 or 1. what should i do?

Comment: Assign the value for the randomDecimal variable inside the loop...

As per your code same random number will be looped 8 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the value for the randomDecimal variable inside the loop...

As per your code same random number will be looped 8 times

Also below code is in correct.

binaryNumber = remainder + "";

As per your requirement it should be

binaryNumber = binaryNumber + remainder + "";